# what does the zero mean in "getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getPackageName(), 0).versionCode" that the method to get the verionCode

Tags: android

Today I googled how to get the version code of a android application.I find that everyone in the internet says like this:

> getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getPackageName(), 0).versionCode

I read the apis,but it just say the second parameter of getPackageInfo is additional option flags.And that page just list a few flag not including 0.
I test using 1,2,512 and so on,the result is the same with using 0.
I just want to know the reason why everyone uses 0 not another number?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

0 means all the flags are turned off

See [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html) page for the meaning of all the flags

Comment: thx for your reply.I have realized that it involves bit computation.